# Error: You do not have permission to create subdomains of the server’s hostname

Tags: cpanel, vps, whmcs

Attempting to add a subdomain to a client's WHM/cPanel VPS. Getting the error:

`There was a problem creating the sub-domain:
You do not have permission to create subdomains of the server’s hostname.`

Answer (score 10):

This was fixed by changing settings in WHM:

`WHM Home -> Server Configuration -> Tweak Settings`

`Allow users to park subdomains of the server’s hostname: ON`

Answer (score 0):

After making the following changes in WHM, I am able to create sub-domains in Users.

> Login to the WHM Panel.
>
> Server Configuration >>> Tweak Settings
>
> Allow users to park subdomains of the server’s hostname.
>
> Click ON Button.
>
> This will provide the users permission to create sub-domains